# javascript/jquery modify a css class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Before loading my page i want to make some modification  on class style.
The style class is included in `MyStyle.css`

```
.divNew {
    float: left; 
    margin: 10px 5px 5px 25px;
}
```

And loading a new page i want to modify/overload the margin and to add height.
Any suggestion?
This is what i've tried:

```
function pageLoad() {
    var theRules = new Array();
    if (document.styleSheets[0].cssRules) {
        theRules = document.styleSheets[0].cssRules;
    } else if (document.styleSheets[0].rules) {
        theRules = document.styleSheets[0].rules;
    }
    for (n in theRules) {
        if (theRules[n].selectorText == 'divNew') { ? ? ? ?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _"Before loading my page i want to make some modification"_, jquery/javascript only runs after the page has completely loaded(i.e., on document ready).

Comment: If you are looking for these changes to be applied before the user sees it then `document ready` suites you just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery on Document ready you could do something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.divNew').css('margin','modifications');  // .css('margin','10px 10px 10px 10px');
    $('.divNew').height(newHeight);  // .height(300)
});
```

For reference

http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: Thanks. Great recommendation. Useful.

Answer (score 1):

Use the jquery css function. It takes an object of CSS properties.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.divNew').css({
        "margin": "10px 5px 5px 25px",
        "height": "100px" //change to whatever your height is
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're over complicating this by a billion percent.

```
$('.divNew').css({'height':'2000px', 'width':'2000px'});
```

just use comma seperated values with the built in jquery css method.